# If a random vector $U \sim f_U(u)$ when does $W= f_U(U) $ have a bounded pdf?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a random vector $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with a bounded pdf $f_U(u)$.  Now suppose we define a new random variable $W=f_U(U)$ with the pdf $f_W(w)$.

What would be a condition on the random vector  $U$ or the pdf of $U$ such that the pdf of $f_W(w)$ is bounded?

I tried going through the classical arguments ( for $n=1$), but I don't think the classical mapping theorem holds

\begin{align}
f_W(w)= f_U(f_U^{-1}(w)) \frac{d}{dw} f_U^{-1}(w)= w  \frac{d}{dw} f_U^{-1}(w)
\end{align}
since the pdf is not always invertable.

Comment: Here are 3 examples: If $U$ has uniform distribution on $[a, b]$, then $W = \frac{1}{b-a}$ almost surely. If $U$ has exponential distribution of rate $\lambda > 0$, then $W$ has uniform distribution on $[0, \lambda]$. If $U$ has the standard normal distribution, then $$f_W(w) = \sqrt{-\frac{2}{\log(\sqrt{2\pi}w)} } \mathbf{1}_{(0,1/\sqrt{2\pi})}(w) $$ and thus develops a power-type singularity of exponent $-1/2$ around $x = 1/\sqrt{2\pi}$. This seems to suggest that the regularity of the function $\omega(w) = |\{x : f_U(x) > w\}|$ plays a role here.

Comment: @SangchulLee  Thanks. In your definition of $\omega(w)$.  What does $| \cdot|$ stand for?

Comment: It denotes the Lebesgue measure of the set. I mentioned this because this is often a good substitute for the inverse of $f_U$ when it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to study this in the case when $f$ is monotonic, which implies it either has compact support or its support contains only one of $\pm\infty$. In that case $f_w(w)=w\frac{1}{f'_U(f_U^{-1}(w))}$, but it seems quite annoying to derive conditions, especially on the denominator that assure boundedness. For example if $f'_U(z)$ can be arbitrarily close to zero, this can cause problems,e.g. a half-normal or half-cauchy distribution. So in this situation if $f$ has compact support, then its enough for $f'_U(z)>\epsilon>0$ for all $z$. Otherwise if the support includes $+\infty$, then you would need $w/f'_U(f_U^{-1}(w))$ to stay bounded.